# Multiprocessing in Pool leads to 0 CPU Usage

Tags: python, excel, pandas, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to get a grasp of multiprocessing using Pool in Python. However, I get 0 CPU usage when I try to run my code in Jupyter Notebook.

I have tried changing the number of processes, arguments in the function, etc. but no success.
The below example is simplified. In my actual work, I am doing the exact same thing but reading in multiple Excel files with just `pool.map(pd.read_excel, filepath)` and get the same problem.

```
python  
from multiprocessing import Pool
pool = Pool(7)

def add_test(y):  
    x=0  
    for i in range(y):  
        x+=1  
    return(x)  

pool.map(add_test, (1000000,1000000, 1000000, 1000000, 1000000, 1000000, 1000000))
```

Comment: Is it possible that your test task is simply finishing faster than you can notice? Try changing `(1000000,1000000, 1000000, 1000000, 1000000, 1000000, 1000000)` to `[10**8] * 7`.

Comment: Good idea, but no it is not. In fact, it is not finishing at all - my Jupyter command is not outputting anything and keeps the [*] rather than a number indicating a completed step.